# aligning multiple div, img and text in CSS - problems

Tags: css

I'm trying to align several DIVS, Images and text and I can't figure this out..

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Heres' my HTML

```
<div class="section5">
<div class="outer">

    <div class="container1">
        <img src="icon.png" width="85">
        <div class="title1">Text</div>
        <div class="subtitle1">Text</div>   
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <img src="iphone.png" width="375"> 
        <div class="subtitle2">Text</div>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.section5{ height: 525px;   background-color: #5e6172;  text-align: center; position: relative;}
.outer{ width: 80%; background-color: #45da45;  height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;} 

.title1{color: #ffffff; font-size: 2.6em; font-family: h35;   }
.subtitle1{color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: h35; margin-top: 0.25em; }
.subtitle2{color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: h35; margin-top: 0.25em; }

.container1{display: block; background-color: #ccc;  }
.container2{display: block; background-color: #fffc1e;   }
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/mib92/hogwohf8/

My current problems:

1) My text at the bottom needs to be on the right side of the image.. center like in my example image.

2) the bottom of my bottom picture must be align to the bottom of container2 AND the bottom of section5

3) While doing this, the container 1 must remain in the vertical middle of the remaining space of the section5.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```css
    .section5 {

      height: 525px;

      background-color: #5e6172;

      text-align: center;

      position: relative;

    }

    .outer {

      width: 80%;

      background-color: #45da45;

      height: 100%;

      margin: 0 auto;

      position: relative;

    }

    .title1 {

      color: #ffffff;

      font-size: 2.6em;

      font-family: h35;

    }

    .subtitle1 {

      color: #ffffff;

      font-size: 1.5em;

      font-family: h35;

      margin-top: 0.25em;

    }

    .subtitle2 {

      color: #ffffff;

      font-size: 1.5em;

      font-family: h35;

      margin-top: 0.25em;

    }

    .container1 {

      display: block;

      background-color: #ccc;

    }

    .container2 {

      display: block;

      background-color: #fffc1e;

    }

    .container1 .wrapper {

      display: inline-block;

      float: right;

    }

    .container2 img {

      margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

```html
<div class="section5">
  <div class="outer">

    <div class="container1">

      <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" width="85">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title1">Text</div>
        <div class="subtitle1">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
      <div class="subtitle2">Text</div>
      <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" width="375">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your text has been align to right to image as want. your image will lie on bottom and your container1 align center. Then what is the issue. give me the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hops it's help you.

```css
.section5 {
      height: 525px;
      background-color: #5e6172;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .outer {
      width: 80%;
      background-color: #45da45;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    .title1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 2.6em;
      font-family: h35;
    }
    .subtitle1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-family: h35;
      margin-top: 0.25em;
    }
    .subtitle2 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-family: h35;
      margin-top: 0.25em;
    }
    .container1 {
      display: block;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .container2 {
      display: block;
      background-color: #fffc1e;
    }
    .right-sied {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 41%;
    }
    .left-sied {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 49%;
    }
    .left-sied img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="section5">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container1">
      <img src="icon.png" width="85">
      <div class="title1">Text</div>
      <div class="subtitle1">Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
      <div class="left-sied">
        <img src="iphone.png" width="375">
      </div>
      <div class="right-sied">
        <div class="subtitle2">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/0hxzwvw6/)**